# How to reference a dynamically created dataframe in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some variables and a dictionary of strings and google sheets imported:

```py
grad_year = '2029'
df_dict = {'grade_1': grade_1_class_2029,
'grade_2': grade_2_class_2029,
'grade_3': grade_3_class_2029,
'grade_4': grade_4_class_2029,
'grade_5': grade_5_class_2029}
```

I then turn the google sheets into dataframes, naming them dynamically:

```py
for key, val in df_dict.items():
    rows = val.get_all_values()
    vars()["df_" + key + "_class_" + grad_year] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        rows[2:], columns=rows[1]
    )
```

Now I would like to reference them without a pre-created dictionary of their names.
There is still a bunch of stuff I would like to do to the new dataframes such as deleting blank rows. I have tried:

```py
for key, val in df_dict.items():
    rows = val.get_all_values()
    vars()["df_" + key + "_class_" + grad_year] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        rows[2:], columns=rows[1]
    )
    vars()["df_" + key + "_class_" + grad_year].replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
    vars()["df_" + key + "_class_" + grad_year].dropna(
        subset=["Last Name"], inplace=True
    )
```

and

```py
for key, val in df_dict.items():
    rows = val.get_all_values()
    vars()["df_" + key + "_class_" + grad_year] = (
        pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows[2:], columns=rows[1])
        .replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
        .dropna(subset=["Last Name"], inplace=True)
    )
```

but neither worked.

Comment: Why don't you use only one dataframe, and add a column with the class_grad name, and filter for the one you need ?

Comment: oh like stack them all and then filter? I guess I could but the tables have quite different columns, so I would need to filter the columns after. Also I was just curious if I could reference a dynamically created dataframe within the same loop it was created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `nan_value` by `pd.NA` (Pandas 1.0.0 and beyond), your first code snippet works fine:

```py
import pandas as pd

grad_year = "2029"

vars()[f"df_{grad_year}"] = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "class": {
            0: "class1",
            1: "class2",
            2: "class3",
            3: "class4",
        },
        "name": {0: "John", 1: "Jack", 2: "", 3: "Butch"},
    }
)
vars()[f"df_{grad_year}"].replace("", pd.NA, inplace=True)
vars()[f"df_{grad_year}"].dropna(subset=["name"], inplace=True)

print(vars()[f"df_{grad_year}"])
# Outputs
    class     name
0  class1     John
1  class2     Jack
3  class4    Butch
```

In your second code snippet, you also have to set `inplace` to `False` instead of `True` both times in order for chain assignments to work:

```py
vars()[f"df_{grad_year}"] = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "class": {
                0: "class1",
                1: "class2",
                2: "class3",
                3: "class4",
            },
            "name": {0: "John", 1: "Jack", 2: "", 3: "Butch"},
        }
    )
    .replace("", pd.NA, inplace=False)
    .dropna(subset=["name"], inplace=False)
)

print(vars()[f"df_{grad_year}"])
# Output
    class     name
0  class1     John
1  class2     Jack
3  class4    Butch
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked. Would you mind giving a little more detail on the inplace? I looked at the documentation and it was not very helpful

Comment: Inplace = True mean that the modification will be applied to the original dataframe, in case of inplace = False, a data frame with modifications is returned(so you have to save it yourself in a variable), but the original dataframe is still the same.